# How do I merge rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// colors
+----+-------+--------+----------+---------+
| id | type  | red_id | green_id | blue_id |
+----+-------+--------+----------+---------+
| 1  | 1     | 51     | NULL     | NULL    |
| 2  | 3     | NULL   | NULL     | 12      |
| 3  | 1     | 423    | NULL     | NULL    |
| 4  | 2     | NULL   | 5432     | NULL    |
| 5  | 2     | NULL   | 10       | NULL    |
+----+-------+--------+----------+---------+
//     ^ type: there is either 1 or 2 or 3 which specifies which color isn't NULL
```

And I want this output:

```
// new_colors
+----+-------+----------+
| id | type  | color_id |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | 1     | 51       |
| 2  | 3     | 12       |
| 3  | 1     | 423      |
| 4  | 2     | 5432     |
| 5  | 2     | 10       |
+----+-------+----------+
```

I think I have to use `CASE .. WHEN` function.

```
SELECT id, type,
         CASE WHEN red_id IS NOT NULL THEN red_id
              WHEN green_id IS NOT NULL THEN green_id
              WHEN blut_id IS NOT NULL THEN blue_id
         END AS color_id
  FROM colors
WHERE 1
```

But I'm trying to write a query depend on the `type` column. I want to use one of those three numbers `1`, `2`, `3` in the `type` column instead of that `CASE .. WHEN`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use COALESCE function in mysql. Coalesce function returns the first non-null value from the list of columns passed to this function as a parameter.

```
select id, type,coalesce(red_id,green_id,blue_id) as color_id from colors
```

Answer (score 4):

Your table is `bad design`. If you have `type` column, you only need the `value` column, not 3 columns like that.

For your case, if only 1 column is not `null`, 2 are `null` then you could use

```
SELECT id, type,
     COALESCE(red_id, green_id, blue_id)
FROM colors;
```

Answer (score 2):

You already know what to do.
A simple change:

```
SELECT id, type,
         CASE WHEN (type = 1) THEN red_id
              WHEN (type = 2) THEN green_id
              WHEN (type = 3) THEN blue_id
         END AS color_id
  FROM colors
WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested but this seems right:
Change your case statement to this*

```
CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN red_id
          WHEN type = 2 THEN green_id
          WHEN type = 3 THEN blue_id
     END AS color_id
```